# Facebook wont load the correct META tags upon sharing

Tags: facebook, meta-tags

I have added META tags for Facebook on my website and according to the [Object Debugger](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug) everything works like a charm. Even the scraped page looks fine for the specific pages on the website.

The problem is that if I copy the URL to a photo (for example [P1220712](http://gallery.erik-edgren.nu/photo/P1220712)) and paste it into the "What's on your mind?" field and wait for it to fetch the META tags, it shows the META for [the front page of my website](http://gallery.erik-edgren.nu/) and not for the photo!

If I enter the URL to the same photo in the Object Debugger and wait till it has loaded every data including the photo and then do the same thing about the "What's on your mind?", it loads the META tags for the photo and everything works fine!

Why do it act like this? Should it not load the META tags from my URL in "What's on your mind?" in the first place?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can’t reproduce your problem, pasting your photo’s URL into the box shows the picture and the description _“Titta mer på fotografiet som togs den 29 juni, 2012.”_ – so most likely just a cache problem.

Comment: Ok. That's weird. I couldn't do that before but now I can. When I try another photo like http://gallery.erik-edgren.nu/photo/P1220740 it won't show anything at all besides of the title and url. I really hope that this is just a cache problem.